# aspdotnet core project build fail on new machin

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, asp.net-core-2.1

Hi I am facing a strange problem,

I have create a asp.net core 2.1 web project, it works/build fine on my machine.

Then I have zipped the project folder with .sln file and moved it to new machin, this also have visual studio 2017, .net core 2.1(it is a VM).

I open the project and when build I get:

> Error     rzc generate exited with code -2147450750.  DEVPROJECT_1    C:\Users\abc.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.1.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets  121

I have even checked the dependency version and they are the same. Both machine are win 7 service pack 1(machine where it works is 64 bit and new machine or vm is 32 bit OS).

Need some way to solve this.

[image]

**[UPDATE 1:]**

Hi I did he clean build as suggested but same issue

> : ------ Rebuild All started: Project: DEVPROJECT_1 , Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\2.1.3\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\2.1.3\hostfxr.dll failed
>     - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
>        http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
>   C:\Users\dev.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.1.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(69,5): error : rzc discover exited with code -2147450750.
>   Done building project "DEVPROJECT_1 .csproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

but when I double click it it redirect me to razor config file and points to this line:

```
<RazorGenerate
  Debug="$(_RazorDebugGenerateCodeTask)"
  DebugTool="$(_RazorDebugGenerateCodeTool)"
  ToolAssembly="$(_RazorToolAssembly)"
  UseServer="$(UseRazorBuildServer)"
  ForceServer="$(_RazorForceBuildServer)"
  SuppressCurrentUserOnlyPipeOptions="$(_RazorSuppressCurrentUserOnlyPipeOptions)"
  PipeName="$(_RazorBuildServerPipeName)"
  Version="$(RazorLangVersion)"
  Configuration="@(ResolvedRazorConfiguration)"
  Extensions="@(ResolvedRazorExtension)"
  Sources="@(RazorGenerateWithTargetPath)"
  ProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
  TagHelperManifest="$(_RazorTagHelperOutputCache)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is odd. Could be caching foul play.

1. Close the Visual Studio
2. Try to get rid of all `.vs` (hidden), `bin` and `obj` folders in your solution
3. Start empty visual studio (don't open the solution yet!)
4. Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)
5. Open your solution, let it restore all NuGet and rebuild

Comment: Hi I did he clean build as suggested but same issue

Answer (score 0):

After some helpful pointers the issue was that "KB2533623" was not installed on the machine, after that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after upgrading dotnet SDK to 3.0.

I resolved it by adding a global.json file and setting SDK to 2.1.504

msdn page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by installing the ASP.NET Core SDK.
You have to install .net core 2.1 sdk, you can download it from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.1.